# How to control a `forest` boxes height

Tags: tikz-pgf, forest

I am doing a horizontal `forest` diagram for enzymes/substrates for a report. In my actual `standalone` file this is how it currently looks:

[image]

I want to use `standalone` so that I can add references and working hyperlinks. However, the boxes containing the text have too much height and the relatively unimportant figure is taking up too much space in my main report document. I have experimented with `s sep` and such but as I think this is a `tikz` issue (that being the height of text boxes) I am unsure what to do only recently having started to learn `tikz`. I definitely do not know how `forest` interacts with `tikz` to set the `node`'s at least.

How can I control the height of a `node` or box that contains "Horse liver alcohol DH" (for example) and reduce the space above and below the words please?

This is how my MWE looks:

[image]

MWE:

```
\documentclass[border=0mm]{standalone}

\usepackage{forest}
\useforestlibrary{edges}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,arrows.meta,automata,backgrounds,calc,
                  fit,shadings,shapes}
\usepackage{chemmacros}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\newcommand\hyperlinkStuff[2]{\scalebox{0.75}{\tiny(\color{blue}{\href{#1}{#2}}\color{black}{)}}}

\begin{forest}
    for tree={%
        grow'=east,
        edge={thick, -Stealth},
        tier/.option=level,
        if level=0{%
            thick,
            draw=none,
            font=\tiny,
            align=left,
            anchor=parent,
            l=-5mm,
            l sep=8mm,
            s sep=0mm,
            }{},
        if level=1{%
            thick,
            draw,
            font=\tiny,
            align=left,
            anchor=parent,
            s sep=0mm,
            }{},%
}
%
[\hspace{-2.08mm}Dehydrogen-\\\hspace{-2.08mm}ases (DH), for children={forked edge}, name=dh
    [\textit{A. fulgidus} \iupac{\L-Alanine} DH \hyperlinkStuff{https://www.brenda-enzymes.org/enzyme.php?ecno=1.4.1.1}{1.4.1.1}, name=afaladh]
    [Horse liver alcohol DH \hyperlinkStuff{https://www.brenda-enzymes.org/enzyme.php?ecno=1.1.1.1}{1.1.1.1}, name=hladh]
    [\iupac{\L-Amino} acid DH \hyperlinkStuff{https://www.brenda-enzymes.org/enzyme.php?ecno=1.4.1.5}{1.4.1.5}, name=aadh]
    [Glutamate DH \hyperlinkStuff{https://www.brenda-enzymes.org/enzyme.php?ecno=1.4.1.2}{1.4.1.2}, name=gdh    ]
    [\iupac{\L-Leucine} DH \hyperlinkStuff{https://www.brenda-enzymes.org/enzyme.php?ecno=1.4.1.9}{1.4.1.9}, name=leucine]
    [Amine DH \hyperlinkStuff{https://www.brenda-enzymes.org/enzyme.php?ecno=1.4.9.1}{1.4.9.1}, name=amdh]
]
%
\node[%above=2pt,
        font=\bfseries\tiny,
        above=4pt,
        anchor=west,
        ] at (afaladh.north west) {Enzyme name \scalebox{0.75}{\tiny(\normalfont EC number)}};
%
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add `inner ysep=1pt` (or any length) to the `for tree`.

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=0mm]{standalone}

\usepackage{forest}
\useforestlibrary{edges}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,arrows.meta,automata,backgrounds,calc,
                  fit,shadings,shapes}
\usepackage{chemmacros}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\newcommand\hyperlinkStuff[2]{\scalebox{0.75}{\tiny(\color{blue}{\href{#1}{#2}}\color{black}{)}}}

\begin{forest}
    for tree={%
        grow'=east,
        inner ysep=1pt,    % <----- Added
        edge={thick, -Stealth},
        tier/.option=level,
        if level=0{%
            thick,
            draw=none,
            font=\tiny,
            align=left,
            anchor=parent,
            l=-5mm,
            l sep=8mm,
            s sep=0mm,
            }{},
        if level=1{%
            thick,
            draw,
            font=\tiny,
            align=left,
            anchor=parent,
            s sep=0mm,
            }{},%
}
%
[\hspace{-2.08mm}Dehydrogen-\\\hspace{-2.08mm}ases (DH), for children={forked edge}, name=dh
    [\textit{A. fulgidus} \iupac{\L-Alanine} DH \hyperlinkStuff{https://www.brenda-enzymes.org/enzyme.php?ecno=1.4.1.1}{1.4.1.1}, name=afaladh]
    [Horse liver alcohol DH \hyperlinkStuff{https://www.brenda-enzymes.org/enzyme.php?ecno=1.1.1.1}{1.1.1.1}, name=hladh]
    [\iupac{\L-Amino} acid DH \hyperlinkStuff{https://www.brenda-enzymes.org/enzyme.php?ecno=1.4.1.5}{1.4.1.5}, name=aadh]
    [Glutamate DH \hyperlinkStuff{https://www.brenda-enzymes.org/enzyme.php?ecno=1.4.1.2}{1.4.1.2}, name=gdh    ]
    [\iupac{\L-Leucine} DH \hyperlinkStuff{https://www.brenda-enzymes.org/enzyme.php?ecno=1.4.1.9}{1.4.1.9}, name=leucine]
    [Amine DH \hyperlinkStuff{https://www.brenda-enzymes.org/enzyme.php?ecno=1.4.9.1}{1.4.9.1}, name=amdh]
]
%
\node[%above=2pt,
        font=\bfseries\tiny,
        above=4pt,
        anchor=west,
        ] at (afaladh.north west) {Enzyme name \scalebox{0.75}{\tiny(\normalfont EC number)}};
%
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

I would write provided tree code as follows:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{forest}
\useforestlibrary{edges}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,arrows.meta,automata,backgrounds,calc,
                  fit,shadings,shapes}
\usepackage{chemmacros}
\usepackage[
    colorlinks=true,
    urlcolor=blue,
            ]{hyperref}  
\newcommand\hyperlinkStuff[2]{\scalebox{0.75}{\href{#1}{#2}}}

\begin{document}
    \begin{forest}
for tree={%
    font=\tiny,
    inner ysep =
    align=left,
    anchor=west,
%            
    grow'=east,
    edge={thick, -Stealth},
forked edge,        % for forked edge
    l sep = 6mm,
 fork sep = 2mm,   
    s sep = 1pt,    % <----
if level=1{draw, thick}{},
tier/.option=level,
            }
%
[Dehydrogen-\\ases (DH), name=dh
    [\textit{A. fulgidus} \iupac{\L-Alanine} DH \hyperlinkStuff{https://www.brenda-enzymes.org/enzyme.php?ecno=1.4.1.1}{1.4.1.1}, name=afaladh]
    [Horse liver alcohol DH \hyperlinkStuff{https://www.brenda-enzymes.org/enzyme.php?ecno=1.1.1.1}{1.1.1.1}, name=hladh]
    [\iupac{\L-Amino} acid DH \hyperlinkStuff{https://www.brenda-enzymes.org/enzyme.php?ecno=1.4.1.5}{1.4.1.5}, name=aadh]
    [Glutamate DH \hyperlinkStuff{https://www.brenda-enzymes.org/enzyme.php?ecno=1.4.1.2}{1.4.1.2}, name=gdh    ]
    [\iupac{\L-Leucine} DH \hyperlinkStuff{https://www.brenda-enzymes.org/enzyme.php?ecno=1.4.1.9}{1.4.1.9}, name=leucine]
    [Amine DH \hyperlinkStuff{https://www.brenda-enzymes.org/enzyme.php?ecno=1.4.9.1}{1.4.9.1}, name=amdh]
]
%
\node[font=\bfseries\tiny,
      above=4pt,
      anchor=west,
      ] at (afaladh.north west) {Enzyme name \scalebox{0.75}{(\normalfont EC number)}};
    \end{forest}
\end{document}
```

As you see, vertical distances between nodes are set by `s sep=1pt` (in code is marked by `<--`). Size of distances you can change as you wish.

[image]

**Edit:**
Apparently for some unknown reason you more prefer that borders of nodes is tight to text, and node has vertical distance for example something like this:

[image]

For this (ugly) result you need to `for tree` options add:

```
    inner ysep = 0.5pt, outer ysep=0pt,
```

and change `s sep = 1pt` to `s sep = 0pt.

**Addendum:**
A possible solution for the first image in question:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage[edges]{forest}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\usepackage{chemmacros}
\usepackage[
    colorlinks=true,
    urlcolor=blue,
            ]{hyperref}
\newcommand\HLscale[2]{\scalebox{0.75}{\href{#1}{#2}}}

\begin{document}
    \begin{forest}
for tree={%
% nodes
    font=\tiny,
    inner sep=2pt, outer sep=0pt,
    align=left,
% tree
    grow'=east,
    anchor=west,
forked edge,        % for forked edge
    l sep = 6mm,
 fork sep = 3mm,
    s sep = 2pt,    % <----
/tikz/arr/.style = {thick, -{Stealth[scale=0.8]}},
if level  = 1{draw, thick}{},
if level> = 3{edge={draw=none}}{edge={arr}},
tier/.option=level,
            }
%
[Dehydrogen-\\ases (DH)
    [\textit{A. fulgidus} \iupac{\L-Alanine} DH
     \HLscale{https://www.brenda-enzymes.org/enzyme.php?ecno=1.4.1.1}{1.4.1.1},
     name=m1
        [L-Alanine, name=n1
            [   [test name, name=t1]]]
    ]
    [Horse liver alcohol DH
     \HLscale{https://www.brenda-enzymes.org/enzyme.php?ecno=1.1.1.1}{1.1.1.1}
        [Ethanol, name=n2
            [   [test name, name=t2]]]
    ]
    [\iupac{\L-Amino} acid DH
     \HLscale{https://www.brenda-enzymes.org/enzyme.php?ecno=1.4.1.5}{1.4.1.5}
        [L-Glicine, name=n3
            [NADPH, name=nadph
                [test name, name=t3]
            ]
        ]
    ]
    [Glutamate DH
     \HLscale{https://www.brenda-enzymes.org/enzyme.php?ecno=1.4.1.2}{1.4.1.2}
        [L-Glicine, name=n4
            [   [test name, name=t4]]
        ]
    ]
    [\iupac{\L-Leucine} DH
     \HLscale{https://www.brenda-enzymes.org/enzyme.php?ecno=1.4.1.9}{1.4.1.9}
        [L-Leucine, name=n5
            [   [test name, name=t5]]
        ]
    ]
    [Amine DH
     \HLscale{https://www.brenda-enzymes.org/enzyme.php?ecno=1.4.9.1}{1.4.9.1},
        [Methylamine, name=n6
            [TTQ, name=ttq
                [Test, name=T]
            ]
        ]
    ]
]
%
\node[inner sep=2pt,
      font=\bfseries\tiny,
      above right,
      ] at (m1.north west) {Enzyme name \scalebox{0.75}{(\normalfont EC number)}};
\draw[thick]
        (nadph.west) -- ++ (-3mm,0) coordinate (aux-1) |- (n1)
        (aux-1)      |- (n2)
        (aux-1)      -- (n3)
        (aux-1)      |- (n4)
        (aux-1)      |- (n5)
%
        (nadph.east) -- ++ (3mm,0) coordinate (aux-2) |- (t1)
        (aux-2)      |- (t2)
        (aux-2)      -- (t3)
        (aux-2)      |- (t4)
        (aux-2)      |- (t5);
\draw[arr]  (n6) -- (ttq);
\draw[arr]  (ttq) -- (T);
    \end{forest}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1 thank you for the answer, I accepted @Sandy G's answer as it covered the `inner ysep` which was the term I was looking for, I hope this is fine. I appreciate the advice on how to better format my `forest` diagrams :)

Comment: @JamesT, it seems that I misunderstood your question. I can reduce vertical separation text from border too, but this lead to my opinion to unpleasant result.

Comment: In my main document I have `draw=none` so the boxes do not exist surrounding the text, I should have made that clear in my question that they were just for showing the box heights, my apologies!

Comment: @JamesT, than your question is misleading ....